# Bootstrap-table: How I modify style and icons of the table-toolbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I do not find to modify the style of the table toolbar. In the definition of the table is: data-toggle='table' when I delete these words the toolbar disappears.

I have found in the file bootstrap-table.js there are definitions to the standard icons of bootstrap but I do not know to change it.

The code of bootstrap-table.js is:

```
 icons: {
            paginationSwitchDown: 'glyphicon-collapse-down icon-chevron-down',
            paginationSwitchUp: 'glyphicon-collapse-up icon-chevron-up',
            refresh: 'glyphicon-refresh icon-refresh',
            toggle: 'glyphicon-list-alt icon-list-alt',
            columns: 'glyphicon-th icon-th',
            detailOpen: 'glyphicon-plus icon-plus',
            detailClose: 'glyphicon-minus icon-minus'
        },
```

I think that to change it I have to create a new entry in the bootstrap.css with these images. I do not know to link my icon images to css file of bootstrap...

Comment: Please provide your whole markup for us to see the proper classes etc...

Comment: What EXACTLY do you want do change? How does it look like now and how is it supposed to look?

Comment: I want to change the glyphicon standar icons for others

Comment: Verify the version of the bootstrap table, you might be using the old one, as this feature added in the new version of bootstrap-table and the way you are doing to update the icon is correct.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have done anything, I do not know to do it. I have found this code but I do not know how to change for my icons.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify bootstrap styles you can just overwrite them with your custom CSS. Look for the classes of the toolbar and apply your changes to these class.

If you have a Button toolbar, e.g. with the following markup:

```
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="...">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">...</div>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">...</div>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">...</div>
</div>
```

You can just apply these rules in your CSS:

```
.btn-toolbar {
    /* your styles */
}
```

Here is an [article about customizing the default bootstrap stlye](https://bootstrapbay.com/blog/customize-bootstrap/).

Comment: Sorry I do not explain me well, I have updated the question.

Comment: I have seen your link of the article about customizing, it's very interesting. Thanks.